# jQuery Accordion and loading content through AJAX

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I would like to load the content under each jQuery [accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) header using the jQuery [load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) command. Currently, I have set this up as the following

```
$(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({          
        header: "h2",
        active: false              
    });

    $("h2", "#accordion").click(function(e) {
        var contentDiv = $(this).next("div");
        contentDiv.load($(this).find("a").attr("href"));      
    });                    
});
```

and the HTML (*relevant snippet*)

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <h2><a href="home.htm">Home</a></h2>
        <div>
           <!-- placeholder for content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="products.htm">Products</a></h2>
        <div>
           <!-- placeholder for content -->       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this all works fine, but there is a problem in that loading content in this manner interrupts the slide down animation of the accordion plugin on some browsers (IE6), and on others (FF), the slide down animation does not occur.

I'm thinking that I would need to prevent the slide down animation from occurring until the content has loaded (using the load callback function) but am unsure how to hook this into the accordion plugin.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post your final solution?

Comment: @HonorGod I posted this question a long time ago and I no longer remember what solution I went with in the end. I'll see if I can revisit this and get a definitive answer

Answer (score 14):

Just a quick heads up.

None of these answers will work as expected with the latest API as since jQuery UI 1.9 the events `change` and `changestart` have been altered to '[activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)' and '[beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate)' respectively.

Hope that saves someone a few minutes.

Answer (score 10):

This should solve your issue:

```
    $('#accordion').accordion({ 
    changestart: function(event, ui){
        var clicked = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').attr('id');
        $('#'+clicked).load('/widgets/'+clicked);
    }
});
```

The trick to it is that accordion changes the classes of the live container, so you can use .find() to locate the active accordion and perform an action on it.

Comment: Actually, this particular code has an error and it doesn't work properly. If you want to find the '.ui.state-active' element, you need to change the event from "changestart" to "change". Otherwise you are invoking the function before jQueryUI have applied the class to the heading element. Result: `change: function(event, ui) { ... }`

Comment: I cannot +1 Danny's comment enough, if you bring up a FF debug window and watch what happens when you do it mogmismo's way, you'll notice that you get the clicked id when you 'collapse' the accordian... not when you expand it... Changing the event to 'change' solves the problem

Comment: Note - with the current version of jqueryui, the event is now `beforeActivate`.  Also, you can get the header which is about to open via `ui.newHeader`

Comment: My advice: check the **version** of the [API here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) because the events have changed

Answer (score 7):

I've just done something similar, and found the trick was to load the content from an ajax request as soon as the DOM is ready, and enable to accordion in the request's callback function.

I tried doing it with jquery's load function, but had trouble, ended up using the ajax function instead.

In your case with multiple ajax calls, i guess you could nest each one in the callback function of the previous. Which is really a horribly inefficient way to do it but if they're just small text files it should be ok.

example as follows:

```
$.ajax({type:"get",url:"home.htm",success: function(data){
    $("#homeDiv").html(data);
    $.ajax({type:"get",url:"products.htm",success: function(data){
            $("#productsDiv").html(data);
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        }
    });
}});
```

that should do it...

Answer (score 7):

I run in to same problem while trying to load accordion in to ajax tabs with Jquery UI.
The accordion cannot be initialised before you destroy it.

Here is example javascript code:

```
    $("#navigation").tabs({ 
    show: function(ui) {
        $('#browse').accordion('destroy').accordion({autoHeight: false, collapsible: true , active: false, header: 'h3'});
    } 
});
```

Comment: I added a .accordion('activate', last_index) at the end of that to pop the last section open when the accordion was collapsible.

Answer (score 5):

I've done this before let me copy and paste it here.

```
<div class="accordion">
    {section name=cat_loop loop=$cats}
            <h3  data-id="{$cats[cat_loop].subcat_id}">
                <a href='#' rel='loaderAnchor' id='lanch-{$cats[cat_loop].subcat_id}'>
                    {print id=$cats[cat_loop].subcat_title}
                </a>
            </h3>
            <div id='section-{$cats[cat_loop].subcat_id}' >
                {include file='include/section_profile_fields.stpl'}
            </div>
    {section}
<div>
```

The stuff inside `{}` contains server-side scripting and is basically a loop to print content for multiple accordions. Here is the javascript:

```
jQuery('.accordion').accordion({
            changestart: function(event, ui){
                   var $activeCord = jQuery(this).find('.ui-state-active');
                   var contentDiv = $activeCord.next("div");
                contentDiv.load('ajax_member_profile_edit.aspx?cat_id='+$activeCord.attr('data-id'));
            }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest and easiest way to do it

```
    $("#accordion").accordion({
                active:false,
                change:function(event, ui) {
                    if(ui.newContent.html()==""){
                        ui.newContent.load(ui.newHeader.find('a').attr('href'));
                        }
                },
                autoHeight: false
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

This should solve the problem of loading the accordion before it is activated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accordion").children("div").each( function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    var ref = $(a).attr("href");
    $(a).attr("href", "#");
    $(this).find("div").load(ref);
  });

  $("#accordion").ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).accordion({
      header: "h2",
      active: false,
      collapsible: true,
      clearStyle: true
    });
  });

})
//]]></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <div><h2><a href="home.htm">Home</a></h2><div></div></div>
  <div><h2><a href="products.htm">Products</a></h2><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking outside the box for a moment, is there any reason you're using ajax to load the content?  It looks, from your example at least, as if the content could just be loaded initially and be done with it.

As for your actually question, have you tried something like this:

```
var contentDiv = $(this).find("div");
```

or explored any other way in which your loading might be interfering with the accordian's view of the DOM tree?  (e.g., trying loading a more deeply nested div)?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of separating/decoupling the content for each accordion pane from the actual "menu" page, and only loading it when necessary. The panes will eventually be dynamically generated from a datasource at runtime...

Comment: There wouldn't be anything wrong in loading the content for each pane upon document ready, other than perhaps performance (I don't know at this stage how many panes there are likely to be in the future).

Comment: Yes, but it would still seem you could do that server-side, as the page is generated, rather than imposing a series of round-trips each time they change tabs.  Most web frameworks support that sort of decoupling without much fuss.

Comment: You've given me food for thought here and I'd probably end up doing that at a later stage. But, I'd still like to solve the original problem!

Comment: So as a first step, try hiding the updated element a little deeper in the structure.  Report back what that does and...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with "try hiding the updated element a little deeper in the structure." I'm pretty sure that the problem occurs because both event handlers (accordion animation and ajax load content) are attached to the onclick event of each accordion pane header.

Comment: And I'm thinking that's not it--that the problem you're having is that the div you are replacing is being used by the accordion, thus interrupting the animation, which is shocked to find the div it's animating no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this isnt entirely the same as whats being talked about here, but a lot of these snippets helped me to get my solution working so i thought id share it incase anyone else needs to do (exactly!) what i needed to do.

i wanted to load external content fragments into an accordion but getting it to resize properly etc was fiddley, heres my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //All the content is loaded at page load which means you dont get screwy animations
    $('#accordion').accordion({
        autoHeight: false, // set to false incase theres loads more in one panel than the others
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $('div#accordion > div').each(function () { //for each accordion panel get the associated content from external file and load it in.
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).load('ajax_content.html #' + id, function () {
                    $('#accordion').accordion('resize');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps someone =)

Oh and i should have mentioned that obviously in the ajax_content.html file there is a  div with a the same id as each of the accordion panels so it knows what to put where!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually much easier than you are all making out!

In your doc ready function:

```
$('#accordion').accordion();
$("#accordion").click(function(e) {
  $('.ui-accordion-content-active').load('/path/to/content');
});
```

and your html

```
<div id = "accordion">
  <h3>Click me</h3>
  <p>Loading....</p>
  <h3>Or even click me!</h3>
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <h3>Etc..</h3>
  <p>Loading</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Have been dealing with this problem, using jquery 1.4 and here is how I solved it. The "ui" object has two important propeties "newContent" and "newHeader". I used newContent and put an id on the div that will hold the content. I also a hidden input tag to hold the important data, It just felt cleaner.

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({
         disabled: false,
         autoHeight: false,
         collapsible: true,
         active: false,
         header: 'h2',
         animated: 'bounceslide',
         changestart: function (event, ui) {
             var location = ui.newContent.find('input:hidden[name=location]').val();
             ui.newContent.find('#data').load(location);


         }

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the simplest answer not yet given, and meets all of the OP's requirements... loads BEFORE the div is shown, and dynamically according to the href of the a tag:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({

    active: false,
    clearStyle: true,
    changestart: function(event, ui){

        var href = $(ui.newHeader.find("a")).attr("href");

        $.post(href, function(data) {

            ui.newHeader.next("div").html(data);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#accordion" ).bind( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {   
    if (ui.newHeader.text()=="LaLaLa"){
       do here ....
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question, and tried a couple of the examples here. However, I  was getting an undefined value using the example with ui-state-active:

```
var clicked = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').attr('id');
```

I also wanted to make sure the .load function was only called the first time each accordion panel was expanded. By combining a couple of other posters answers I got the result I wanted:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
    changestart: function(event, ui){
         if(ui.newContent.html() == ""){
             var id = ui.newContent.attr("id");
             ui.newContent.load("[your url]" + id);
         }
});
```