# JQuery Accordion doesn't 'accordionize' new panels loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui-accordion

I have to load accordion panels into one of my pages using AJAX and I'm finding that JQuery is 'accordionizing' all of the panels defined in the HTML file, but none of the panels loaded via Javascript. One other little quirk: I'm doing this on a nested accordion - the accordion within an accordion. It's accordion inception, if you will.

I checked other Stack Overflow questions and the JQuery Forum and I found that most of them are about resizing panels after loading data. The closest question I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646415/jquery-accordion-and-loading-content-through-ajax), but it doesn't answer my question because trying to destroy and then re-accordion-ize my JS-loaded panels does not work.

**This is the relevant section of my html head section:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true, 
        icons: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false 
    });
  });  
</script>
```

**This is the relevant section of my html body section:**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3 id="acc1">First panel title</h3>
    <div>First panel content</div>

    <h3 id="acc2">Second panel title</h3>
    <div class="accordion" id="ajaxresults-aliaslist">This is where the nested accordion goes</div>

    <h3 id="acc3">Third panel title</h3>
    <div>Thirdpanel content</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ajaxresults-aliaslist").load("/loadaliaslist/");
</script>
```

**When javascript loads "/loadaliaslist/", it received a message with the following content:**

```
<h3>1st panel within a panel title</h3>
<div>1st panel within a panel content</div>

<h3>2nd panel within a panel title</h3>
<div>2nd panel within a panel content</div>

<h3>3rd panel within a panel title</h3>
<div>3rd panel within a panel content</div>
```

I know that the content above is being passed to the div because the content appears un-accordionized when I load the page. Instead of an accordion within an accordion, I just get a bunch of boring content sitting at the first level of the dream sequence. I've got to go down a level... Wait, where was I?

**Right, one more thing: I have tried two things that did not work:**
- I tried putting both the load and the accordion scripts at the bottom of the page (load first), hoping that the order would matter. (noobish? not sure...)
- I tried adding a script at the end to destroy and recreate the panels like so:

```
$("#ajaxresults-aliaslist").accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

That's all. I really hope someone out there is the Leonardo DiCaprio of accordions, and can help rescue me from my predicament. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT FROM OP: SOLUTION FOUND

After playing around more, I found a way to solve this problem as long as AJAX is loading the new data immediately on pageload. Solution was to call the accordion function, only once, immediately after the load. As in the solution below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#ajaxresults-aliaslist").load("/loadaliaslist/",  
    function(response, status, xhr) {    
    if (status == "error") {   
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an <strong>error</strong>: ";   
        $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);   
    }  
/* All panels are accordionized immediately after loading the content */   
    $(".accordion").accordion({   
        collapsible: true,  
        icons: false,  
        autoHeight: false,  
        active: false  
     });   
});   
</script>
```

A word of caution: This will only work if all of the accordion content is loaded immediately. If there are pieces of content loaded after the first accor

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try something like this...

The issue is most likely due to the fact that the event handlers aren't being attached to the inserted content (via Ajax).

```
$(function() {
    var config = {
        collapsible: true, 
        icons: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    }
    $(".accordion").live('load', function(){
        $(this).accordion(config);
    }).accordion(config);
});
```

EDIT: Changed the code a bit (still untested).

Comment: I gave it a try, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Just checking: I replaced my original $(document).ready(function) with this one, and I put it at the end of the page. Is that were you would execute this script?

Comment: Try putting that inside the $(document).ready function. I didn't include it because I thought it would be redundant.

Comment: No dice. Is there a way to confirm your hypothesis about the event handlers?

Comment: Check out the live() docs: "The .live() method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM through the use of event delegation" http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I looked into the live() docs and tried to solve the problem with live, but was not able to bind it properly. I found a solution to my problem, however. See edit for solution. Thanks again @wdm

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to reset the accordion control. Try to do this:

```
$('#accordion')[0].innerHTML = "";
```

After that fill the control with your HTML using the append.