# ajax load accordion when clicked on active tab

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion to create, rename and delete folders. In the rename and delete I have a dropdown with a list of the folders that were created. So when I create a folder it does an ajax call to create a folder, however when I go back to the rename or delete I want to see the updated folders. I have an ajax method to retrieve the list but I am not sure how to call the load function.

I tried

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
        change: function(event, ui){
                var clicked = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').attr('id');
                $('#'+clicked).load("serveresource method");
        }
});
```

from one of the posts in [jQuery Accordion and loading content through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646415/jquery-accordion-and-loading-content-through-ajax)
When I tried to alert the clicked value it is undefined, not sure what should be in it. Any help wpuld be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do something like this..**

```
 $('#accordion').find('.ui-state-default').click(function(){
        var clicked =$('#accordion').find('.ui-state-active').attr('id');
        alert(clicked);
        $('#'+clicked).load("serveresource method");

});
```